# Render same component with different details each time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, render

I want the same message with different URL, based on a prop. I basically have the below render method, which I call inside my main one.

```
  renderNoBasicMode = () => {
    const { securityMode } = this.props;
    // Need this, while isFetching securityMode === '',
    // Unless, we don't this is rendering on multipel renders.
    if (securityMode !== SecurityMode.BASIC && securityMode !== SecurityMode.EMPTY) {
      return (
        <div className="badge badge-light" data-test="non-basic-mode">
          <NoResource
            icon="user-o"
            title="Non Basic Security Mode"
            primaryBtn="New User"
            primaryCallback={this.openCreateUserModalPromise}
            moreUrl={NonBasicSecurityMode.url}
          >
            No users available when Lenses is running on {securityMode} security mode.
          </NoResource>
        </div>
      );
    }
    return null;
  };
```

And I want to display a different url based on the value of the NonBasicSecurityMode, which I have here:

```
const NonBasicSecurityMode = [
  { securityMode: 'mode1', url: 'https://...' },
  { securityMode: 'mode2', url: 'https://...' },
  { securityMode: 'mode3', url: 'https://...' }
];
```

The securityMode, is deternment by an API request.

```
export const securityModeSelector = createSelector(
  lensesConfigSelector,
  config => (config.&& config['security.mode']) || ''
);

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    securityMode: securityModeSelector(state),
  };
}
```

Basically, I tried mapping through them, and a forEach, but I was apparently wrong. Can you help me figure this out? Thanks!!

Comment: it was better to put your array map approach to see what was wrong

Comment: and also, `NonBasicSecurityMode.url` is for sure wrong, how does your component even render now?